# Excel to CSV file issue with encoding

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a csv file with UTF-8 encoding that I'm using with some Python code. Everything is working fine, but now I want to rearrange the rows in the csv file and re-run my code on the file. 
However, when I open it in Excel for Mac 2016, sort the rows alphabetically and then re-save it as a csv file I run into a problem. I've tried re-saving the csv file in 4 different file formats (Comma Separated Values, CSV UTF-8, Windows Comma Separated, MS-DOS Comma Separated) but they all give me different errors when I try to run the file through my code. In one version it's no longer UTF-8 encoded, in another there's no quotes in empty fields, etc.

Is there a way to sort the rows of a csv file in Excel and then re-save it as a csv file without altering the file in any way besides the sorting of the rows?

Comment: Why are you sorting in Excel? You can apply your sorting in Python.

Comment: Mostly because it was easier in my case. I don't have experience with sorting csv files in Python and I thought there must be some way to re-save it without altering the encoding.

Comment: Opening CSV files in Excel and re-saving can be flat out dangerous.  Excel gets a little to eager to "help" with data import.  If you have a string that in purely numeric, Excel decides it must be a number.  Have leading zeros - too bad, they are gone.  Oh. was that number really big?  How about I convert it to scientific notation for funsies.  You can always used "Data Import -> From Text", but no one ever does.  I have customers who insist on making Unique IDs pure numeric with leading zeros, they wonder why their stuff keeps breaking.  It doesn't like or respect you.  It does what it wants.

Comment: It sounds like you're not only struggling with *encoding* but also *formatting* of the file. The encoding is UTF-8. But you can also change formatting options, like field separator and quoting options. I don't have Excel in front of me at the moment, but in LibreOffice you have to click something like "Edit filter settings" when saving the file. BUT, this does NOT qualify as "without altering the file", which I don't think is possible in Excel.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I understand now that it's just generally a bad idea to try and use Excel for this. I'll read about sorting csv files in Python and solve it that way.